# Github Pages hosting my repo as a sub domain

Tags: github, dns, subdomain, github-pages, namecheap

I Made a portfolio website for myself and hosted it using my own custom domain ([`arnabkumar.me`](http://arnabkumar.me/)) but its automatically hosting it to [`arnabkumar.me/myportfolio`](http://arnabkumar.me/myportfolio/) (Note: here "myportfolio is my repository name") i tried tons of things nothing worked can anyone please suggest me what to do Its hosted on `Namecheap.com`. The [repository](https://github.com/19arnab190201/myportfolio).

Answer (score 1):

Domains are configured per user or organization. The **myportfolio** part is the repository. You cannot configure a single repository as the APEX or subdomain without the repository as the path component.